# How to add wildcard query in Hibernate Search 3.1.1GA

Tags: hibernate-search

how add wildcard query when using hibernate search. I am using Hibernate Search 3.1.1GA jar and unable to upgrade my jar to upper version. In upper version of hibernate we can use wildcard method using Query Builder.

I am stuck please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the Hibernate Search query DSL. Something like this:

```
Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder
    .keyword()
      .wildcard()
    .onField("foo")
    .matching("bar*")
    .createQuery();
```

This DSL is indeed not part Search 3.1.1 and was added later. In this version you need to build your queries by using native Lucene queries. Really all the Search DSL does is under the hood building these native queries for you. In your case you want to look at `org.apache.lucene.search.WildcardQuery` or you could use the `org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser` to use the Lucene query syntax which also allows wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for help.  QueryBuilder is not available for my version. Please share more code.

Comment: That's what I am saying, you don't need a QueryBuilder. You build native Lucene queries. Check the Hibernate Search docs as well as the Lucene one. There are heaps of examples.

Comment: Hardy : I did as you suggest but in got exception .           Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.search.SearchFactory.buildQueryBuilder()Lorg/hibernate/search/query/dsl/QueryContextBuilder;
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)

Comment: Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(NSAliasImpl.class).add(Restrictions.eq("itemId", itemId));
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(NSAliasImpl.class).get();

Comment: org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("trackerId").ignoreAnalyzer().matching("*" + searchParam + "*").createQuery();

Comment: Is that possible with a array of strings in onFields();? Please see my question @Hardy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528012/how-to-search-with-wildcards-in-fields