# How to search with wildcards in multiple fields?

Tags: hibernate, wildcard, hibernate-search

I'm trying to implement a search based on hibernate-search. 
I managed to combine search-fields based on some condition, but in this case, I can not search with wildcards.

```
    List<String> spalten = new ArrayList<String>();

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search
            .getFullTextEntityManager(em);

    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(BeitragVO.class).get();

    List<BeitragVO> results;
        // add fields for search
        List<String> fields= new ArrayList<String>();

        if (student) {
            logger.info("hit student");
            spalten.add("user.surname");
            spalten.add("user.givenname");
        }
        if (company) {
            logger.info("hit company");
            spalten.add("company.name");
        }

        for (String string : fields) {
            logger.info(string);
        }
        logger.info("Searchterm:" + searchterm);
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword()
                .onFields(fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]))
                .matching(searchterm).createQuery();

        logger.info("Query: " + luceneQuery.toString());

        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager
                .createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, ArticleVO.class);

        results= jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

Under my search input, I got six checkboxes, the user can check or not. 
If the user checks student, the search only applies for the table for students. This works totally fine!

Problem:
Search input: Alexan
(for Alexander)

No result is found!

I tried something like this, for wildcard search:

```
    TermContext tc = qb.keyword();

    WildcardContext wcc = tc.wildcard();
       if (student) {

            TermMatchingContext tmc = wcc.onField("user.surname");
            tmc = tmc.andField("user.givenname");
            luceneQuery = tmc.matching(searchterm).createQuery();
        }
```

This is correct syntax and I get the correct query (user.surname:alexander user.givenname: alexander). But still an empty resultlist.

I really like the attempt without wildcards. Is there a way to add wildcard-search on this attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the wildcard '*' it should work. Effectively you need to build something like:

```
qb.keyword()
  .wildcard()
  .onField( "user.givenname" )
  .matching( "Alex*" )
  .createQuery();
```

Apparently, you need to decompose the DSL to add some conditional logic, but it should work. Are you sure that 'searchterm' in your example has the wildcard added?

An alternative to decomposing the DSL could be to create multiple independent queries and combine them via a `BooleanQuery`. I think that would be more readable.

The issue/bug/feature got fixed! You can see it here:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1811

Comment: Well, my point is: It does work with a single field (with wildcard()), but the method onFields() is not available for wildcard(). That 'searchterm' does NOT contain the wildcard. Even not, if I add the * into that term! 

I thought about BooleanQuery, but could not figured out, how they could be helpful in my case.

Comment: Regarding ...wildcard().onFields()... - I think this is really a bug/missing feature. You could create a JIRA issue here - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH. Regarding the boolean query. Check this example http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_combining_queries. All you need to do, is to create a query per field and combine them. Last but not least, the '*' gets in your case removed, because without wildcard() the analyzer will remove it.

Comment: Is there any chance, that the feature will be implemented or the bug will be fixed within the next two or three month?

Comment: Don't know. Create the issue and take it from there. If you want to increase the chances that it gets integrated, provide a fix. It's Open Source after all and contributions are always welcome :-)

Comment: Just created the issue, but I'm not really good at this. :D https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1811 
You know, what my point is, maybe you can edit it a bit if it is not correctly. :-) Thank you, so far!

Answer (score 0):

only **Alexan** will be assumed as exact match, try with **Alexan***

Comment: I got many Alexanders and Alex's in my database. Only exact matches will be found. Even with *.
Example:
Al = no result
Al* = no result
Alex = results

Comment: yes wildcard lucene query expect * or ? character as a regular expression